# How to overrride HttpContext in mocked RewriteContex?

Tags: c#, .net-core, mocking, moq

I have mocked `RewriteContext`:

```
 Mock<RewriteContext> rewriteContextMock = new Mock<RewriteContext>();
```

Then I try to override its `HttpContext` with a mock:

```
rewriteContextMock.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.Request).Returns(requestMock.Object);
```

unfortunately that causes

> Unsupported expression: x => x.HttpContext
>       Non-overridable members (here: RewriteContext.get_HttpContext) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.'

So what I did was

```
 Mock<HttpContext> httpContextMock = new Mock<HttpContext>();      
 rewriteContextMock.Object.HttpContext = httpContextMock.Object;
```

But the the question raises: Is there any point in using `Setup()`, `Return()` chain when setting up the properites? Have I solved the problem correctly or I should use different approach?

Comment: Well, why do you need a mocks for concrete classes here?

Comment: Without proper context about what it is you are trying to achieve there is not much help that we can provide.

Comment: If you would provide how the context is to be used in the subject under test, a more direct answer can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

[RewriteContext](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Middleware/Rewrite/src/RewriteContext.cs) is a simple POCO with no behavior,

```
/// <summary>
/// A context object for <see cref="RewriteMiddleware"/>
/// </summary>
public class RewriteContext
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets and sets the <see cref="HttpContext"/>
    /// </summary>
    public HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets and sets the File Provider for file and directory checks.
    /// </summary>
    public IFileProvider StaticFileProvider { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets and sets the logger
    /// </summary>
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; } = NullLogger.Instance;

    /// <summary>
    /// A shared result that is set appropriately by each rule for the next action that
    /// should be taken. See <see cref="RuleResult"/>
    /// </summary>
    public RuleResult Result { get; set; }

    internal StringBuilder Builder { get; set; } = new StringBuilder(64);
}
```

so there is no need to mock it.

All its members can be easily provided as needed to an actual instance of the object.

```
//...

RewriteContext rewriteContext = new RewriteContext();

var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
httpContext.Request.Scheme = "http";
httpContext.Request.Host = new HostString("localhost");
//...set other members

rewriteContext.HttpContext = httpContext;

//...
```

Comment: But `rewriteContext.HttpContext.Request`  is read-only, I can't set it without mocking it, or can  I?

Comment: @Yoda [that it is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.defaulthttpcontext.request?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_DefaultHttpContext_Request). my bad.  just populate the desired properties of the context. it is created internallay by the default http context so wont be null

Comment: @Yoda again, will need to see how this is to be used to provide a more direct answer